# ¿Porque se genera Notice: Undefined index al intentar validar varios radio buttons en un formulario?

Tags: php, validación, radiobutton

Tengo un formulario con varios radio buttons que necesito validar con php, tengo dos archivos uno llamado inscripciones.php en donde proceso los datos del formulario y otro inscripciones.view.php que contiene la vista, como se tiene que mostrar un mensaje de error debajo de cada campo si es que llega a existir, envio los datos a la misma pagina, mi problema es que cuando intento validar un grupo de radio button me aparece el siguiente error **Notice: Undefined index: grado in C:\xampp\htdocs\ColegioJRF\inscripciones.php on line 9** ya verifique en ambos archivos este bien definido el name="grado" sin embargo el error sigue apareciendo.

Mi codigo inscripciones.view.php es:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" class="f1 shadow" novalidate>

    <h4 class="text-center pb-3">Pre-registro</h4>
    <p class="text-center pb-4">Completa el siguiente formulario:</p>

    <div class="container">
        <h5 class="pb-3"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Datos del alumno</h5>

        <div class="form-radio">
            <label>Inscripción a:</label>
            <div class="form-row pt-2 text-center" id="campo-radio">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="primero" name="grado" value="1">
                    <label for="primero">1° Kinder</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="segundo" name="grado" value="2" >
                    <label for="segundo">2° Kinder</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="tercero" name="grado" value="3">
                    <label for="tercero">3° Kinder</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="tercero" name="grado" value="4">
                    <label for="tercero">4° Kinder</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="tercero" name="grado" value="5">
                    <label for="tercero">5° Kinder</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="radio" id="tercero" name="grado" value="6">
                    <label for="tercero">6° Kinder</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if(!empty($error_grado)): ?>
                <small class="error"><?php echo $error_grado; ?></small>
            <?php endif;?>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row pt-1 pt-3">
            <div class="group col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" name="ap-pat-alu" autocomplete="off" required><span class="barra"></span>
               <label for="ap-pat-alu" class="float-label">Apellido paterno:</label>
               <?php if(!empty($error_apellido1)): ?>
                   <small class="error"><?php echo $error_apellido1; ?></small>
               <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            <div class="group col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="ap-mat-alu" id="ap-mat-alu" autocomplete="off" required><span class="barra"></span>
                <label for="ap-mat-alu" class="float-label" id="text-label-2">Apellido materno:</label>
                <?php if(!empty($error_grado)): ?>
                   <small class="error"><?php echo $error_apellido2; ?></small>
                <?php endif;?>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="f1-button">
              <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-form-primary">Enviar ></button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y el código de inscripciones.php es

```
<?php

    require 'admin/config.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $grado = $_POST['grado'];
        $ap_pat_alu = $_POST['ap-pat-alu'];
        $ap_mat_alu = $_POST['ap-mat-alu'];
        $nombre_alu = $_POST['nombre-alu'];
        $edad_alu = $_POST['edad-alu'];

        if(empty($grado)){
            $error_grado = 'Selecciona una opción</br>'; 
        }

        if(empty($ap_pat_alu)){
            $error_apellido1 = 'Ingresa un apellido.</br>'; 
        } 

        if(empty($ap_pat_alu)){
            $error_apellido2 = 'Ingresa un apellido.</br>'; 
        } 

  require 'views/inscripciones.view.php';
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema para que ya no se muestre el error? Solo es en este tipo de campo en donde aparece ya que en los de apellido no tuve problema alguno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando los `radio` no son marcados no se envían con el formulario. Para evitar el *`Undefined index`* puedes hacer algo así:

```
   require 'admin/config.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $grado =      !empty($_POST['grado'])      ? $_POST['grado']      : NULL;
        $ap_pat_alu = !empty($_POST['ap_pat_alu']) ? $_POST['ap_pat_alu'] : NULL;
        $ap_mat_alu = !empty($_POST['ap_mat_alu']) ? $_POST['ap_mat_alu'] : NULL;
        $nombre_alu = !empty($_POST['nombre_alu']) ? $_POST['nombre_alu'] : NULL;
        $edad_alu =   !empty($_POST['edad_alu'])   ? $_POST['edad_alu']   : NULL;

        if($grado){
            $error_grado = 'Selecciona una opción</br>'; 
        }

        if($ap_pat_alu){
            $error_apellido1 = 'Ingresa un apellido.</br>'; 
        } 

        if($ap_pat_alu){
            $error_apellido2 = 'Ingresa un apellido.</br>'; 
        } 

  require 'views/inscripciones.view.php';
```

Simplemente, en vez usar `empty` en los `if`, lo usas en un ternario para:

1. Verificar si el dato no está vacío en el POST
2. Si no está vacío lo recuperas en su respectiva variable, si está vacío asignas a la variable el valor `NULL`
3. Finalmente, usas cada variable limpiamente para evaluar o lo que haga falta.

**PD:** Aunque haya validaciones en el servidor, considera validar también en el cliente.

Comment: gracias me funciona correctamente, solo tengo una duda en cuanto a la validación del lado del cliente, en primera instancia mi idea era validar con jquery todos los datos y después enviarlos a otra página como recibe datos.php y volver a validar, investigue como hacerlo pero la mayoría te explican el procedimiento con ajax, pero como tal no me sirve ese metodo porque con estos datos tengo que crear un pdf, es por eso que decidi por motivos de simplicidad manejar solo la validación del lado del servidor. ¿Como podría hacer esa validación? O me podrías ayudar con algun ejemplo?

Comment: @AndreaEscobar Ajax no es para validar realmente, sino **para poder enviar los datos desde el cliente al servidor sin necesidad de recargar la página**. Su uso sería lo recomendable, porque desde el punto de UX (experiencia del usuario) podrías enviar, recibir, cambiar... elementos tanto en el cliente como en el servidor de una forma totalmente transparente y además elegante (la página no se recarga) y con eso ganas también en rendimiento. **Validar** es otra cosa que no tiene nada que ver con Ajax... [+]

Comment: [+] Validar sería por ejemplo **controlar que el formulario no se envíe si ciertos campos están vacíos** y eso de puede hacer de múltiples formas. Un ejemplo de validación sencillo es cuando el botón `Enviar` está desactivado o invisible mientras no se cumplen ciertos criterios. Eso lo puedes hacer por ti misma o bien usando alguna herramienta de ayuda para ello. En cualquier caso, eso sería tema para otra pregunta. Lo importante aquí es que entiendas la diferencia entre Ajax y lo que significa *validar*  del lado del cliente.